# Prove that any group $G$ with $|G|=588$ is solvable

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory, p-groups, solvable-groups

I'm stuck trying to solve this problem from my abstract algebra course:

> Prove that every group of order $588$ is solvable (If you assume that all groups of certain order are solvable, you must prove it too).

First I noticed that $588=2^2\cdot 3\cdot 7^2$, so I guess the prove will use Sylow $p$-subgroups, but I don't find right what I need to do. Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have the right idea. Hint : Which divisors of $588$ or congruent to $1$ modulo $7$ ?

Comment: @Peter The 588 divisors (not using $7,7^2$) are $2,3,4,6,12$, but no one of this is congruent to $1$ modulo $7$ (I don't know if I misundertood your hint). Thanks for helping.

Comment: ... and $1$ is also a divisor of $588/49 = 12$, I guess.

Comment: @Marktmeister Oh of course. So that shows that there's only $1$ Sylow $7$-subgroup right? And, naming that group $P_7$, then I need to prove that $G/P_7$ is solvable right?

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso Exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have seen, using Sylow's theorems, that there is only one Sylow $7$ subgroup, calling it $P_7$.

Then $G/P_7$ has order $12$.

But any group of order $p^2q$ is solvable.

Hence $G/P_7$ is solvable.

Then since $P_7$ is solvable, $G$ is solvable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do I prove that any group of order $p^2q$ is solvable?

Comment: I'm guessing, but, there should be only one Sylow $p$ subgroup, which is solvable, and the quotient would have order $q$, so be solvable.

Comment: This is not entirely trivial: if $|G|=p^2q$, $p,q$ prime, then $G$ has either a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup, or a normal Sylow $q$-subgroup, see for example I.M. Isaacs, *Finite Group Theory*, $(1.31)$Theorem.

Comment: I already did it, don't worry. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: @NickyHekster  Thanks for the touch up.  I did over-simplify it.

Comment: You can also use Burnside's theorem.